# What does "::" mean in c++?

Tags: c++, class, function

I have code I am going over that looks like this:

```
foo::foofa(string n){
    loadFoo(fn);
}
```

What does the foo::foofa mean? I do not quite understand what does :: do? Thanks.

EDIT: Also, is there another way to write this without the :: or is it required?

Comment: @NickVaccaro It's hard to google `::` if you don't know it's called *scope resolution operator*. What the OP needs to do is [read a book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @Praetorian I copied and pasted the question title, and the result showed up immediately.

Comment: @Nick So it does; I stand corrected!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`::` is the scope operator to used to identify and specify the context that an identifier refers to.

using a very **simple** google search, IBM describes it as:

> The :: (scope resolution) operator is used to qualify hidden names so
>   that you can still use them. You can use the unary scope operator if a
>   namespace scope or global scope name is hidden by an explicit
>   declaration of the same name in a block or class.

Comment: Is there another way this code could be written without the :: or is that required?

Comment: no, the scope operator allows you to access these class functions. Without the scope operator the compiler will treat these as individual and unique functions.

Answer (score 8):

> I do not quite understand what does :: do?

It's the *scope resolution* operator.

If `foo` is a class (or a namespace), and `foofa` is something declared inside that class, then within the class you can refer to it simply as `foofa`. But outside the class, you need to use this operator to specify that you mean this particular `foo::foofa`; there could be others scoped inside other classes or namespaces.

> Also, is there another way to write this without the `::` or is it required?

It's required outside the class definition. You could define the function inside the class:

```
class foo {
    void foofa(string n) { // No foo:: needed here
        loadFoo(n);
    }
};
```

If `foo` is a namespace, then you can also use `using` to avoid the need for `::` but that's often a bad idea, so I won't show you how.

Answer (score 2):

```
::
```

is the `scope resolution` operator.
Quoted from [Scope Resolution Operator](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp7a.doc/language/ref/clrc05cplr175.htm)

> The :: (scope resolution) operator is used to qualify hidden names so that you can still use them. You can use the unary scope operator if a namespace scope or global scope name is hidden by an explicit declaration of the same name in a block or class.
>
> You can also use the class scope operator to qualify class names or class member names. If a class member name is hidden, you can use it by qualifying it with its class name and the class scope operator.

Answer (score 1):

:: indicates a scope.  So either a namespace or class name.  For instance if you want to access the sort function in the standard (std) namespace you would use

```
std::sort
```